# SelectAll() behaves differently between MouseClick and Enter events in C# 2015

Tags: c#, enter, mouseclick-event, selectall

I'm trying to highlight text in every controls as it enters.  It works fine when I'm using **MouseClick** event.  But when using **Enter** event, it doesn't work.  I need to use Enter event instead of MouseClick event because I want to highlight the text no matter how each control gets focus.  I can debug the Enter event, and can see that it's processing through. But for some reason SelectAll() is not being processed at all.  Why the different behavior?

```
// This works
private void ClientEdit_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Control c = sender as Control;
    if (c is TextBox) (sender as TextBox).SelectAll();
    else if (c is MaskedTextBox) (sender as MaskedTextBox).SelectAll();
}

// This does not work
private void ClientEdit_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control c = sender as Control;
    if (c is TextBox) (sender as TextBox).SelectAll();
    else if (c is MaskedTextBox) (sender as MaskedTextBox).SelectAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a post about 2 years ago by @Jack-Fairfield, shown below, and it works!

```
private void maskedTextBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BeginInvoke((Action) delegate { SetMaskedTextBoxSelectAll((MaskedTextBox) sender); });
}

private void SetMaskedTextBoxSelectAll(MaskedTextBox txtbox)
{
    txtbox.SelectAll();
}
```

I just started here and don't have enough reputation to give him the credit.  Thanks.